# Dynamically toggle resource column visibility

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a FullCalendar scheduler on a webapp which has 2 way databinding for resources and events, all working great.  I want to be able to present the user with a dropdown that enables them to toggle the visibility of a column, ideally completely client side.

I have tried a combination of addResource / removeResource however my issue here is that a rerender of the calendar (e.g. when a new event is added)  then displays the previously removed resource.  I can work  around this however would prefer a really simple approach using JS / CSS.  I currently cannot find a way to set a resource to not be visible, or to have zero width - is this possible?

Comment: "a rerender of the calendar (e.g. when a new event is added) then displays the previously removed resource". Can you show code which reproduces this? I can't make it do that - see demo at http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/10/ - click the "remove resource" button to delete a resource using fullcalendar's removeResource, then drag on the calendar to add an event. The removed resource stays removed. Is your page posting back when creating an event, or something?

Comment: @ADyson It will add the resources again if `refetchResourcesOnNavigate` is true. Not sure if OP has that option set, but it's a problem I currently have.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way to do this:

1. Store resources in an array variable *resourceData*.
2. Create another array called *visibleResourceIds* to store the ids of any resources you want to show.
3. In the resources callback function, filter *resourceData* to only contain the resources where the resource id exists in *visibleResourceIds*. Return the filtered array and fullcalendar will only add the desired resources for you.

To remove a resource from view, simply remove the resource id from *visibleResourceIds* and refetchResources. To add the resource back in, add the id to *visibleResourceIds* and refetchResources. DONE.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ceth270f/19/)

```
var resourceData = [
  {id: "1", title: "R1"},
  {id: "2", title: "R2"},
  {id: "3", title: "R3"}
];

var visibleResourceIds = ["1", "2", "3"];

// Your button/dropdown will trigger this function. Feed it resourceId.
function toggleResource(resourceId) {
  var index = visibleResourceIds.indexOf(resourceId);
  if (index !== -1) {
    visibleResourceIds.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    visibleResourceIds.push(resourceId);
  }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaDay',

  resources: function(callback) {
    // Filter resources by whether their id is in visibleResourceIds.
    var filteredResources = [];
    filteredResources = resourceData.filter(function(x) {
      return visibleResourceIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1;
    });
    callback(filteredResources);
  }
});
```

Comment: For people using FullCalendar 5:
Change `resources: function(callback) {`
to:`resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {`
and 
`callfack(filteredResources)` to 
`successCallback(filteredResources);`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge. Instead of a dropdown, I use checkboxes, but the workings will be the same.

My resources are stored in a variable, when I uncheck a box, the resource is removed and the resource's object is added to another array with the resourceId as key, and the index added to the object to restore the object in the same column as it originally was. When re-checking the box, the object is added to the resources array and the resources refetched.

```
/* retrieve the resources from the server */
var planningResources;
var removedResource = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '/planning/resources/',
    method: 'get',
    success: function (response) {
        planningResources = response;
        showCalendar();
    }
    , error: function () {
        if (typeof console == "object") {
            console.log(xhr.status + "," + xhr.responseText + "," + textStatus + "," + error);
        }
    }
});

/* create the calendar */
showCalendar = function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
    });
}

/* checkbox on click */
$('.resource').click(function() {
    var resourceId = $(this).val();
    var hideResource = !$(this)[0].checked;
    $('.status:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    });
    if(hideResource) {
        $.each(planningResources, function(index, value){
            if( value && value.id == resourceId ) {
                value.ndx = index;
                removedResource[resourceId] = value;
                planningResources.splice(index,1);
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('#planningoverview').fullCalendar(
            'removeResource',
            resourceId
        );
    }
    else {
        planningResources.splice(removedResource[resourceId].ndx, 0, removedResource[resourceId]);
        $('#planningoverview').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    }
});

showCalendar();
```

It probably doesn't get first price in a beauty contest, but it works for me ...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resourceColumns` option for this. In the column objects you can set the `width` property to a number of pixels or a percentage. If you pass a function here you can easily handle the *width* property someplace else. Your hide/show function can then set the *width* to 0 to hide the column. After that you can trigger `reinitView` to update the view: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar("reinitView");`