# Fullcalendar Scheduler: resourceRender can't seem to access the all-day td cells

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to use the "resourceRender" callback in fullcalendar scheduler to dynamically hide resource columns from the agenda day view.

The callback function supplies labelTds and bodyTds parameters by default, but  bodyTds is empty in agenda view. I thought I could select the tds using jquery but it doesn't select the all-day row cells. I expected the code below to color all the cells red but maybe those tds aren't loaded yet when resourceRender fires. Can this be done?

```
calendar = $CALENDAR.fullCalendar({
    resourceRender: function(resource, labelTds, bodyTds){
        if (bodyTds.length === 0) {
            bodyTds = $("td").find(`[data-resource-id=${resource.id}]`);
        }
        labelTds.css("background-color", "red");
        bodyTds.css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

[DEMO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzgoQ.png)

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0sergv3y/30/)

[image: Image of where the red should be (see "red" labels)]

Comment: create js fiddle and share full code!!

Comment: @BhumiShah I added a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a bug to me really...I'd raise it, assuming no-one already has: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: @ADyson Fair enough. I'll report if it hasn't been already. In fairness, the documentation states that the labelTds and bodyTds params are not available in certain views, but I thought I could get around that by manually selecting them with JQuery. I think the all-day tds elements are not yet created when  resourceRender fires so there is nothing to select.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have changed code to apply red color to all tds: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0sergv3y/57/

```
.fc-unthemed td.fc-today{
     background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't color the all-day bodyTds for the initial view, only subsequent view changes seem to work. This is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/17mkLFJ

Comment: Also this solution targets all tds on the page which is not an ideal approach.

Comment: can you create an image of what you want in red?

Comment: I added an image to the original post showing the cells I want to affect.

Comment: You can do it simply overridding css!! updated above!!

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I think my original point is being lost. I wanted a way to _dynamically_ hide or format resource columns individually based on resource-specific criteria. E.g. if a resource has the property important: true we could dynamically style that resource red. Or if the resource is in an array hiddenResources, we hide columns with bodyTds.hide(); labelTds.hide().

CSS is a good way to style the whole calendar but not to handle resources dynamically.

Comment: P.S. I found a good way to hide resources which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427602/dynamically-toggle-resource-column-visibility?rq=1